# What is the best way to desirialize this string of json?

Tags: c#, ios, json, xamarin

I was wondering how I could at best deserialize this json string. For doing that I am using Newtonsoft.json as a plugin with Xamarin.

I only need the parts that says "transaction" and the array in it "transactions" in a list.

```
{
  "id": 999,
  "transactions": [
    {
      "order": 1,
      "displayName": "01_lgn",
      "transaction": {
        "id": 7791,
        "name": "01_lgn",
        "description": null,
        "warning": 1,
        "poor": 2,
        "timeOut": 45,
        "tolerated": 3,
        "frustrated": 7,
        "state": 1,
        "includeInThroughputCalculation": true
      }
    }
    {
      "order": 2,
      "displayName": "02",
      "transaction": {
        "id": 7793,
        "name": "02",
        "description": null,
        "warning": 1,
        "poor": 2,
        "timeOut": 45,
        "tolerated": 3,
        "frustrated": 7,
        "state": 1,
        "includeInThroughputCalculation": true
      }
    }
  ],
  "defies": null,
  "state": 1,
  "reportDisplayName": "testSomething"
}
```

What I already have tried is to put it in a strongly typed class and then make a list of it.

```
public class testTransaction
    {
        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("state")]
        public int State { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("reportDisplayName")]
        public string ReportDisplayName { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("transactions")]
        public List<testTransactions> testTransactions { get; set; }
    }

public class testTransactions
    {
        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("description")]
        public object Description { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("warning")]
        public int Warning { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("poor")]
        public int Poor { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("timeOut")]
        public int TimeOut { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("tolerated")]
        public int Tolerated { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("frustrated")]
        public int Frustrated { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("state")]
        public int State { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("includeInThroughputCalculation")]
        public bool IncludeInThroughputCalculation { get; set; }
    }
```

But when I try to deserialize it in this way the "searchResult" is empty and I see that nothing is added to the list.

```
var bleh = jsonstring;
JObject parsedketenObject = JObject.Parse(bleh);
IList<JToken> jTokenResults1 = parsedketenObject;
IList<JToken> jTokenResults2 = parsedketenObject ["transactions"].Children ().ToList ();
IList<JToken> jTokenResults3 = parsedketenObject["transactions"][0]["transaction"].Children().ToList();
_Transactions_list = new List<testTransaction>();

foreach (JToken result in jTokenResults2)
{
     testTransaction searchResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<testTransaction>(result.ToString());
     _Transactions_list.Add(searchResult);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, the JSON seems to be malformed, you are missing comma.

```
{
  "id": 999,
  "transactions": [
    {
      "order": 1,
      "displayName": "01_lgn",
      "transaction": {
        "id": 7791,
        "name": "01_lgn",
        "description": null,
        "warning": 1,
        "poor": 2,
        "timeOut": 45,
        "tolerated": 3,
        "frustrated": 7,
        "state": 1,
        "includeInThroughputCalculation": true
      }
    },   <-------- HERE
    {
      "order": 2,
      "displayName": "02",
      "transaction": {
        "id": 7793,
        "name": "02",
        "description": null,
        "warning": 1,
        "poor": 2,
        "timeOut": 45,
        "tolerated": 3,
        "frustrated": 7,
        "state": 1,
        "includeInThroughputCalculation": true
      }
    }
  ],
  "defies": null,
  "state": 1,
  "reportDisplayName": "testSomething"
}
```

Additionally, try these for your POCO instead:

```
public class TransactionDetails
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public object description { get; set; }
    public int warning { get; set; }
    public int poor { get; set; }
    public int timeOut { get; set; }
    public int tolerated { get; set; }
    public int frustrated { get; set; }
    public int state { get; set; }
    public bool includeInThroughputCalculation { get; set; }
}

public class Transaction
{
    public int order { get; set; }
    public string displayName { get; set; }
    public TransactionDetails transaction { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public List<Transaction> transactions { get; set; }
    public object defies { get; set; }
    public int state { get; set; }
    public string reportDisplayName { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can use

```
var x = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(blah);
```

x will contain `transactions`, which is already a list.

Comment: Thank you for you comment on my post and that you are willing to help me. I have just tied your code and I think I'm getting somewhere, but for now I got this error message back from Newtonsoft.json.jsonReadException "Input string '1.0' is not a valid integer. Path 'transactions[0].transaction.warning', line 1, position 496." Could it be that there is something wrong in the Strongly typed class? @Blueberry

Comment: No problem.  Double check that the JSON string is actually 1 and not 1.0.  You could try changing the type of warning in the TransactionDetails class to double or even string depending on your usage.

Comment: Thanks again. It is working now. Some integers had to be strings. But I have one last question. Maybe you can help me with this. How can I now show value x in a UITableViewController? @Blueberry

Comment: You are welcome.  I think there will be better placed people to answer your question of you post it on SO.  I'm not an iOS expert.

Comment: Ps. If the answer is correct, you should mark it as such to help future users.

Comment: An addition to the answer from @Blueberry. To be more like you are used to C# you can change your properties to an upper first latter. There is also a useful website called json2csharp.com where you can past you json and it automatically creates the poco for you.

Answer (score 0):

This method is **not strongly typed**, but it will work:

```
var jsonString = GetTheJson(); // however you get your json

dynamic jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);
foreach (var txn in jsonObject.transactions)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", txn.order, txn.displayName, txn.transaction.id);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

The best way to serialize/deserialize a json string to json object is using Google Gson library. You should create DTO files and use its type to serialize the string.
The documentation can be found here: https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html

Comment: suggesting a java library for a question tagged c# is not that helpful